# How to optimize this approach in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to group the data which is on daily grain on basis of monthly and weekly. Then i try to find out for the respective week what is the last 6 week and 6 month aggregated value.

**note: data is huge~30M in my case.**

So the approach i am following now is creating multiple temp tables such as one for weekly level aggregated data, second for monthly aggregated data and so on. So here is my complete approach. Can anyone suggest a approach to make it optimised.

**Update:** added input and expected output

Input:

[image]

expected ouput:

[image]

```
--Date dim
    create temp table date_dim(report_end_wk,start_dt,end_dt,wkno) as(
    select to_date('2019-08-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-07-28','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-08-03','YYYY-MM-DD'),31 union
    select to_date('2019-07-27','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-07-21','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-07-27','YYYY-MM-DD'),30 union
    select to_date('2019-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-07-14','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2019-07-20','YYYY-MM-DD'),29);

    --main table with data at daily grain
    create temp table t1(daily_dt,tvtype,sale) as(
    select to_date('2019-07-29','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mitv',3000 union
    select to_date('2019-08-02','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mitv',3000 union
    select to_date('2019-07-30','YYYY-MM-DD'),'samsung',4000 union
    select to_date('2019-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'samsung',3000 union
    select to_date('2019-07-23','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mitv',2000 union
    select to_date('2019-07-26','YYYY-MM-DD'),'mitv',3000 union
    select to_date('2019-07-22','YYYY-MM-DD'),'samsung',9000 union
    select to_date('2019-07-25','YYYY-MM-DD'),'samsung',3000 );

    --getting aggregation as weekly grain
    create temp table wk_level_agg as(
    select report_end_wk,wkno,to_date(report_end_wk,'YYYY-MM') as monthly_dt,tvtype,sum(sale) as wk_sale from t1 join date_dim on daily_dt between start_dt and end_dt
    group by report_end_wk,wkno,to_date(report_end_wk,'YYYY-MM'),tvtype);

    --getting aggregation as monthly grain
    create temp table month_level_agg as(
    select  monthly_dt, tvtype, sum(wk_sale) as monthly_sale from wk_level_agg
    group by monthly_dt,tvtype);

    --getting last 6 week aggregated data at column level. here i have used only last week for example
    create temp table wk_hist_agg as(
    select report_end_wk,wkno,monthly_dt,tvtype,wk_sale, sum(wk_1_sale) as wk_1_sale from(
    select a.*, CASE
                   WHEN nvl (datediff (week,b.report_end_wk,a.report_end_wk),0) = 1 THEN b.wk_sale
                   ELSE 0
                 END AS wk_1_sale from wk_level_agg a
    left join wk_level_agg b
    on a.tvtype=b.tvtype and  (b.report_end_wk BETWEEN TRUNC (dateadd (week,-6,a.report_end_wk))
                  AND TRUNC (dateadd (week,-1,a.report_end_wk))))
                  group by report_end_wk,wkno,monthly_dt,tvtype,wk_sale);

    --getting last 6 month aggregated data at column level. here i have used only last 1 month for example
    create temp table month_hist_agg as(
    select monthly_dt,tvtype,monthly_sale, sum(mth_1_sale) as mth_1_sale from(
    select a.*, CASE
                   WHEN nvl (datediff (month,b.monthly_dt,a.monthly_dt),0) = 1 THEN b.monthly_sale
                   ELSE 0
                 END AS mth_1_sale from month_level_agg a
    left join month_level_agg b
    on a.tvtype=b.tvtype and  (b.monthly_dt BETWEEN TRUNC (dateadd (month,-6,a.monthly_dt))
                  AND TRUNC (dateadd (month,-1,a.monthly_dt))))
                  group by monthly_dt,tvtype,monthly_sale);


    --final table data at weekly level and last 6 week and monthly aggregated data at column level
    select a.*,b.monthly_sale,b.mth_1_sale from 
    wk_hist_agg a left join month_hist_agg b on a.monthly_dt=b.monthly_dt and a.tvtype=b.tvtype
    order by a.report_end_wk desc;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just a hint - in Redshift you can use `'2019-08-14'` as `DATE` - it will be implicitly casted. Or just explicitly cast is `'2019-08-14'::DATE`

Comment: @gordon i will update the question with input and output details soon

Answer (score 2):

I see many little optimization tips I could give you. I am not sure though I will have time to assemble them all in an example.

1. Use [common table expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html) - so called `WITH` statements instead of temp tables. Temp tables may turn out faster, but Redshift should be fast enough to handle aggregations (in your case of 10s or 100s millions of rows).

   You would have a single query, and declare each temp table step as a *table variable*:

   ```
   WITH
       my_first_table as (SELECT ... ),
       my_second_table as (SELECT ... FROM my_first_table ),
       my_third_table as (SELECT ... FROM my_second_table )
   SELECT 
       ...
   FROM any_of_the_above_declared_tables
   ```
2. use [`DATE_TRUNC`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) to produce different granularity of dates:

   ```
   SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', '2019-08-14'::DATE);  -- will return 2019-08-01 
   SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', '2019-08-14'::DATE);  -- will return 2019-08-12
   ```
3. Use [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html) to get the calendar week:

   ```
   select to_char('2019-08-14'::DATE, 'WW');  -- returns 33
   ```
4. It may be easier to use `SUM(CASE WHEN date_condition THEN value END)` to get the sums for a period of time - but that depends on how you structure your transformations

Comment: any other way you could suggest instead of writing these many codes